# playwright, cucumber in nx

Tags: nrwl-nx, nrwl

Is there any way to setup e2e test with Playwright and Cucumber instead of cypress? I need to use from playwright and cucumber as it's test runner in my nx project.

Comment: Maybe these docs will help you - https://tally-b.medium.com/e2e-testing-with-cucumber-and-playwright-9584d3ef3360 & https://code-maven.com/implementing-a-feature-in-typescript-cucumber-playwright

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use https://github.com/marksandspencer/nx-plugins/tree/main/packages/nx-playwright

You will need to install the plugin using

```
yarn add --dev @mands/nx-playwright
yarn playwright install --with-deps
```

> Remove existing e2e app `nx generate remove <APP-NAME>-e2e` before generating a new one

Generate new e2e app

`yarn nx generate @mands/nx-playwright:project <APP-NAME>-e2e --project <APP-NAME>`

PS: I am also author of the plugin

Answer (score 0):

Older question but I also ran into this issue and couldn't find much help when searching, really just this post and an issue on the NX Github repo.

I was able to get it working using the [playwright-bdd](https://vitalets.github.io/playwright-bdd/#/getting-started) package. You can see how I set it up here:

https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/19970#issuecomment-1808275822